Costructing two quotient rings $\mathcal O_K / I$ and $\mathcal O_K / J$ that have the same cardinality but are not isomorphic.
It is a well known fact that for nonzero prime ideals $I,J$ of $\mathcal O_K$ ($K$ a number field), if the quotient rings $\mathcal O_K / I$ and $\mathcal O_K / J$ have the same cardinality then they are isomorphic. The assumption that they are nonzero prime ideals is important here. I'm trying to construct a counterexample to show that this may not necessarily be the case if we don't assume that both $I$ and $J$ are nonzero prime ideals. What I've tried so far: Consider $O_K = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}] \cong \mathbb Z[x] / (x^2 - 3)$. If we take $I = (3)$ then $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}] / (3)$ should be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_9$ (?). If I can construct another ideal $J$ such that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}] / J$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$ then that would work, but doing so amounts to finding some polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\mathbb Z[x] / (3,x^2 - 3, p(x) \cong \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$, which has been extremely tricky to do.
Any $\textit{hints}$ would be appreciated. Thanks.

If $P$ and $Q$ are two different prime ideals with the same norm (for example, Galois conjugates) then consider $I = PQ, J = P^2$.

@QiaochuYuan Sorry could you elaborate on what you mean by prime ideals that correspond to "Galois conjugates"?

I mean prime ideals which are related by the action of the Galois group. For example in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ every prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ splits into a product of conjugate prime Gaussian integers, e.g. $(5) = (2 + i)(2 - i)$, and you can use these as $P$ and $Q$.

@QiaochuYuan Right, but now how would one go about showing that $\mathbb Z[i] / P^2 \not\cong \mathbb Z[i] / PQ$? If it was true, would that imply that $P^2 = PQ$? Why would equality hold?

One of them has a nilpotent and the other one doesn't.

Consider the example Qiaochu Yuan mentioned in his comment.
In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $(5)=(2+i)(2-i)$. Let $P=(2+i)$ and $Q=(2-i)$. Then since $P$ and $Q$ are coprime,  we have $$\mathbb{Z}[i] / PQ \simeq \mathbb{Z}[i] / P \oplus \mathbb{Z}[i] / Q \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5.$$
Now we consider $\mathbb{Z}[i] / P^2=\mathbb{Z}[i] / (3+4i)=\{ \overline{a+bi} \ | \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ where $\overline{a+bi}$ denotes the equivalent class.  Note that $3+4i,4-3i \in (3+4i)$, so $7+i \in (3+4i)$, which means that we can only consider representative elements of the form $k,k \in \mathbb{Z}$. It can be verified that $3+4i \mid k$ iff $25 \mid k$. Hence, $$\mathbb{Z}[i] / (3+4i)=\{ \overline{k} \ | \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \}=\{ \overline{k} \ | \ k \in \mathbb{Z},0 \leq k \leq 24 \} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{25},$$ so $\mathbb{Z}[i] / PQ \ncong \mathbb{Z}[i] / P^2.$
There is also another way of seeing that $\mathbb{Z}[i] / P^2 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{25}$: see this question When are $\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak p^m$ and $\mathbb Z/p^m\mathbb Z$ isomorphic as $\mathbb Z$ modules?.
By the way, in your example, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}] / (3) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, not $\mathbb{Z}_9$.

By the way, I can not find a general result of the structure of $\mathcal{O}_K / P^2$ for a prime ideal $P$ of $\mathcal{O}K$. If $e(P|p)=f(P|p)=1$, then $\mathcal{O}K / P^2 \simeq \mathbb{Z}{p^2}$. If $f=1$ and $e \geq 2$, then $\mathcal{O}K / P^2 \simeq \mathbb{Z}{p} \oplus \mathbb{Z}{p}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. However, when $f \geq 2$ the question seems more complicated and hard to deal with...
